# Python: how to extract data from figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, phase

I have two sin signals with the same frequency, and I plot a lissajou figure using them:
[image]

Now I want to calculate the phase difference between them. To do that, I have to know the values of a and b. How can I extract the value from the figure? By this I mean the exact coordinates of the largest x-position and the x-position where the curve crosses the zero line.

As example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
t=np.arange(0,1.0,1.0/8000)
U=np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t)
I=np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t+45)
plt.plot(U,I)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can almost certainly calculate this based on the data you are passing to matplotlib without trying to extract data from the matplotlib figure.

Comment: You mean like read the value directly from the figure？Yes but I want it to be more precise so :)

Comment: You plotted the figure from the data. Why don't you use the same data to calculate the phase difference?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your data set so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: please see the new edition thx ~

Comment: you should forget your graph and stick to the maths instead.

Comment: The phase difference is 45, because you plugged that number into your code. Since it makes more sense to look at phase difference modulo the whole circle, you may want to look at 45 % (2*pi) = 1.018 or 58 degrees.

Comment: I know this is just a example, what I have are two sin signals with unknow phase difference

Comment: How can it be unknown, if you plot it?